# Fetch data from different tables using while loop and if statement

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, fetch

I am attempting to fetch data from my database using 8 different tables named:

`inventory descriptorid typeid conditionid statusid locationid stationid users`

I believe my query is working correctly the problem is using my `$row` variable. I am only getting the results from data in the inventory table. Can Someone explain how I can fetch my data from each table?

The code is below:

```
<?php
    // get the records from the database
    if ($result = $con->query("
    SELECT inventory.InventoryID, descriptorid.dename, typeid.tyname, 
           inventory.Serial, inventory.ServiceTag, inventory.CityTag, 
           conditioncid.conname, statusid.statusname, locationid.locname, 
           stationid.stationname, users.Fname, users.Lname, 
           inventory.PurchaseDate, inventory.POnumber 
    FROM inventory 
    LEFT JOIN descriptorid 
      ON inventory.Descriptor = descriptorid.dename 
    LEFT JOIN typeid 
      ON inventory.Type = typeid.tyname 
    LEFT JOIN conditioncid 
      ON inventory.ConditionC = conditioncid.conname 
    LEFT JOIN statusid 
      ON inventory.Status = statusid.statusname 
    LEFT JOIN locationid 
      ON inventory.Location = locationid.locname 
    LEFT JOIN stationid 
      ON inventory.Station = stationid.stationname 
    LEFT JOIN users 
      ON inventory.cuserFname = users.Fname 
     AND inventory.cuserLname = users.Lname "))
    {
    // display records if there are records to display
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            // display records in a table
            echo "<table border id='myTable' class='tablesorter' >";

            // set table headers
            echo "<thead><th>ID</th><th>Descriptor</th><th>Type</th><th>Serial</th><th>ServiceTag</th><th>CityTag</th><th>Condition</th><th>Status</th><th>Location</th><th>Station</th><th>CurrentUser</th><th>Lastname</th><th>PurchaseDate</th><th>POnumber</th><th></th><th></th></thead>";


            echo "<tbody";

            while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
            {
                // dump whats returned
                // print_r($row);

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->InventoryID . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->Descriptor . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->Type . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->Serial . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->ServiceTag . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->CityTag . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->ConditionC . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->Status . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->Location . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->Station . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->cUserFname . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->cUserLname . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->PurchaseDate . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->POnumber . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='invrecords.php?InventoryID=" . $row->InventoryID . "'><img src='img/default/button_mini_ticket_edit.gif'></a></td>";
                echo '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="confirmation(' . $row->InventoryID . ');"><img src="img/default/button_mini_delete.gif"></a>';
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your row vars as you select them (as you did it with the columns of the inventory table):

Wrong:

```
        echo "<td>" . $row->Descriptor . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->Type . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->ConditionC . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->Status . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->Location . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->Station . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->cUserFname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->cUserLname . "</td>";
```

Use instead:

```
        echo "<td>" . $row->dename . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->tyname. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->conname. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->statusname. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->locname. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->stationname. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->Fname. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->Lname. "</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? That means that if you have table A and B you only take elements which are located in A but not necessarily in B. That means if there is not a matching partner for an element of the left table, you would have a row containg an element of table A in one column and `null` in the other column.
This might be one reason for having a resultset only containing an element of the `inventory` table.
As far as I understand you want a result containing the elements joined on equal attributes, so try to replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

[image: SQL Joins]

Image source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: That is not correct. LEFT JOIN means that it takes rows of table A even if there is no corresponding row in table B, but if there is, you get the result of table B, too (except you exclude them with "WHERE B.Key IS NULL" which is one line below in your excellent graph).

Comment: Sorry for my misknowledge, as far as I understood it, it joins both tables based on what you have specified in the `ON` clause and then takes only the elements located on the right side.
Does that mean that you have the full table A in the result?

Comment: In this case with no WHERE clause: yes

Comment: You're right, I recognized it on my own image now. Shame on me. But I think in his case an `INNER JOIN` would work, wouldn't it? A `LEFT JOIN` would produce a result only containing informatik from `inventory` if there is nothing on the right side, is it right? I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am attempting to use an id that is in the inventory table to connect to the data in the other tables. I don't wish to keep data fetched from both tables just the ID from descriptorid,typeid, etc. How can I replace that ID in inventory to match the id and name of the table I am joining it to?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't fully understand your question. Could you explain to me what you're meaning with "How can I replace that ID in inventory to match the id and name of the table I am joining it to?" or could give me an example?

Comment: I have the names for condition, type, etc. in my inventor table as integers to relate to the ID of the conditionid, typeid, etc. tables. I plan to eventually use them as a drop down box feature how can I use the integer I put in the inventory table to match the id of the table and option I want it to fetch the data from?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was instead of matching the third option (dename, tyname,etc.) on my secondary tables with the inventory I should've been matching it with the ID of that said table. Now when I query the third option with my row variable I can select any option from my secondary table (deid,tyid). It now outputs the desired results and hopefully I can create a drop down list using a similar query.Thanks for all the ideas.